# Auto-updatable links

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

Is there a way to apply "auto-updatable" style for hyperlink?

I believe, this question is not trivial.

When you normally click on hyperlink, it will change it's color to violet. Next, if you save, close, and then reopen the document, the link will be updated back to blue. This is default behaviour of Word, and there is no need to use any macros for it.

I'm trying to replicate this behaviour with VBA. Here is the code:

```
Sub Test1()
    Selection.Range.Hyperlinks(1).Range.Fields(1).Result.Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHyperlinkFollowed
End Sub
```

To make it work, simply put caret into the link, run macro, and see the results:

[image]

This works fine, except such visited links will not be auto-updated after you save, close, and then reopen the document. See the difference in the picture below. The link "Google" was opened normally, using the mouse Ctrl-click; the link "StackOverflow" was opened using the macro:

[image]

As I already said, I want to make my VBA-opened links (StackOverflow) auto-updatable as well (as Google).

Yes, I understand, there is a workaround - simply create another macro, which will be started every time the document opened and change all violet hyperlinks back to blue. However, this is just workaround, and I don't like it. Using it, we use conversion from "permanent violet" to "permanent blue", instead of using "temporary violet" (that's mean, auto-updatable without any additional efforts).

Hope everything is clear. Thanks in advance.

**Update** (was added after several answers were already posted).

Yes, I understand, this will work:

```
Sub Test1()
    On Error Resume Next 'To avoid an error in case if the link isn't reachable
    Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow
End Sub
```

But I want just *simulate* following, without really opening the link in the browser. That's why, I can't use `Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove the line, the link will change once followed and change back once the doc is reopened.

```
Selection.Range.Hyperlinks(1).Range.Fields(1).Result.Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHyperlinkFollowed
```

Comment: My bad. It was a bit wrong code in my original post. I edited it.

Comment: that line is what is making the color stay the followed link color.  If you remove it and follow the link via a macro, like your original sample code,  it changes to the followed color.  Close the document and reopen and it is back to blue.  you are setting the style of that link when you do that and word writes that into the xml so it can apply it again when it is reopened.

Comment: Yes, I understand everything you said. The point is, that in real life, the macro should only simulate opening, instead of really opening it in the browser. But, I want to simulate it as close to "real opening" as possible. My current approach (using `Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHyperlinkFollowed`) is not close enough, because it have "permanent", instead of "temporary" nature.

Comment: then you are left to put a macro, say on close, and change the hyperlink styles back. I assume this is what MS is doing since there is an Option in the Options to reset Hyperlinks.

Comment: Did you mean the workaround mentioned in the bottom of my original post? And what option did you mean? There is an option "Update automatic links at open" but even if disabled, links keep updating.

Answer (score 1):

this does it for me

```
Sub resetHyperlinks()

    Dim hLink As Hyperlink

    For Each hLink In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
        hLink.Address = hLink.Address        ' this works
 '      hLink.ScreenTip = hLink.ScreenTip    ' this works also

    Next hLink


End Sub
```

Comment: Heh, that is exactly what the OP calls a "workaround". It wouldn't work if Word stored visited status for URLs rather than Hypelink objects. (And since this little detail is undocumented, it's subject to change without notice.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the style with code to make the link purple.  Just use the `Follow` method.  This will click the link and turn it purple and then it will be reset to blue upon opening the document again.

```
Sub Test1()
    Selection.Range.Hyperlinks(1).Follow
End Sub
```

Comment: If would also open the hyperlink, and the OP didn't mention if they want it.

Comment: He said "I want to make my VBA-opened links (StackOverflow) auto-updatable as well".  So it sounds to me like he wants the link to open and turn purple and then turn back to blue after the file is saved, closed, and reopened.

Comment: @J.Garth Hi. Thanks. Please, take a look at comments below Sorceri's answer. The point is, in my task I should avoid using "Follow".

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by you "don't want a work around" and "with no additional efforts"? Does no additional efforts mean you don't want to write custom code for every project? So maybe a class you could import and instantiate at the workbook Open or Close events would be a good solution? There are a few answers that seem to indicate that it's not clear exactly what you are trying to achieve since what you're asking does not seem to be functionality already provided by MS. Your further constraint of "no workarounds or additional effort" seems to negate all possibility of a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset link styles with VBA code that runs at startup, i.e. is a part of [`Document_Open()` routine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211897%28v=office.11%29.aspx) in [`ThisDocument` VBA module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa189914(v=office.10).aspx).

The [`Hyperlink` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/hyperlink-object-word) doesn't have any `.Visited` property or anything relevant (i.e. you cannot even see if it was visited), so there's no other way beside `.Follow()` that also opens the link as it should.

- You're basically trying to falsify the information that the document provides about its state: make a link appear visited when it actually wasn't.
- The fact that the class doesn't even provide a property means that Word's designers do not consider the visited status a part of the editor's functionality (i.e. it effectively doesn't exist as far as the program's job is concerned).

This evidence suggests that **Word doesn't, and is not designed to, have any specialized facility to switch link status other than `.Follow()`.** Which means, any way that you find that happens to have the desired effect in bound to be what you're calling a "workaround".

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Does I understand it correctly, that it is the workaround mentioned in my original post?

Comment: I can't see why this is a workaround if you need nonstandard behavior. To get nonstandard behavior, you hook into relevant places in the app and provide your custom code to run. But whatever.

Comment: explained how nothing short of what you call "workaround" is possible here.

Answer (score 1):

The "temporary" color of a followed hyperlink is an embedded (and not directly accessible) feature of the built-in Hyperlink character style.  It is not exposed through the normal UI's Style tools, nor through the object model.

You can readily compare all formatting between two selections using the Reveal Formatting pane (Shift+F1) in the document window in Word.

If you compare a normally followed hyperlink with a hyperlink affected by your snippet, you'll see that the followed hyperlink *still has the Hyperlink style*, while your simulated follow has *changed the style* of the second hyperlink.

If you compare a never-followed hyperlink and a normally followed hyperink, Word identifies their formatting as ***exactly*** the same. Word does not acknowledge that any aspect of formatting (style, font color, etc.) has changed.

It seems likely that the `Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHyperlinkFollowed` you are using exists explicitly to address this gap (which is somewhat disappointing).

I recommend using your existing approach, and then reverting the style in a procedure triggered by the `Before Save` and `Before Close` events of the document. Using those events will prevent the followed style from saving at all, and so avoid issues caused by someone opening the document without enabling macros.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
 Dim HL As Hyperlink
 For Each HL In Sheet1.Hyperlinks
   HL.Range.Style.Font.Color = vbBlue    
 Next
End Sub
```

Can't you simply make it any colour you want without invoking it. As others have stated above whatever you you I think will be a work around as it's not an intended function.